# Use AWS Lambda to run Sagemaker Batch Transform job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to place a csv file in an S3 bucket and get predictions from a Sagemaker model using batch transform job automatically. I would like to do that by using s3 event notification (upon csv upload) to trigger a Lambda function which would do a batch transform job. The lambda function I have written so far is this:

```
import boto3
sagemaker = boto3.client('sagemaker')

input_data_path = 's3://yeex/upload/examples.csv'.format(default_bucket, 's3://yeex/upload/', 'examples.csv')
output_data_path = 's3://nooz/download/'.format(default_bucket, 's3://nooz/download')

transform_job = sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
    model_name = y_xgboost_21,
    instance_count = 1,
    instance_type = 'ml.m5.large',
    strategy = 'SingleRecord',
    assemble_with = 'Line',
    output_path = output_data_path,
    base_transform_job_name='y-test-batch',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session(),
    accept = 'text/csv')

transform_job.transform(data = input_data_path, 
                        content_type = 'text/csv', 
                        split_type = 'Line')
```

The error it returns is that object sagemaker does not have module transform
What is the syntax I should use in Lambda function?

Comment: The error is telling you that `transformer` is not a valid method that you can call on a `sagemaker` client. You can review the available methods here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html

Comment: `import sagemaker` (not boto3) might work.

Answer (score 0):

While [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) (`boto3.client("sagemaker")`) is the *general-purpose* AWS SDK for Python across different services, examples that you might see referencing classes like `Estimator`, `Transformer`, `Predictor` and etc are referring to the [SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (`import sagemaker`).

In general I'd say (almost?) anything that can be done in one *can* also be done in the other as they use the same underlying service APIs - but the purpose of the SM Python SDK is to provide higher-level abstractions and useful utilities: For example transparently zipping and uploading a `source_dir` to S3 to deliver ["script mode" training](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#train-a-model-with-the-sagemaker-python-sdk).

As far as I'm aware, the SageMaker Python SDK is still not pre-installed in AWS Lambda Python runtimes by default: But it is an [open-source](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk) and [pip-installable](https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker/) package.

So you have 2 choices here:

1. Continue using boto3 and create your transform job via the low-level [create_transform_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_transform_job) API
2. Install `sagemaker` in your Python Lambda bundle (Tools like AWS SAM or CDK might make this process easier) and instead `import sagemaker` so you can use the `Transformer` and other high-level Python APIs.